# how can I print in data of two array in same order

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, sorting

I want to search some data in two different arrays like this;

```
$arr1[]=('2019-10-3', '2019-10-9', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-21',);
```

and the other array il like this;

```
for($i=1;$i<31;$i++){ $arr2[]=date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-'.$i; }
```

now I want to print to screen if `$arr1` data is in `$arr2` '1' else '0' in the same order like this

```
if($arr2['0']==$arr1[0]){echo '1' ;} else {echo '0'}

 '2019-10-1' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
 '2019-10-2' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
 '2019-10-3' is in $arr1 echo '1',
'2019-10-4' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
'2019-10-5' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
'2019-10-6' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
'2019-10-7' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
'2019-10-8' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
'2019-10-9' is in $arr1 echo '1',
'2019-10-10' is in $arr1 echo '1',
'2019-10-11' is not in $arr1 echo '0',
....
```

I use this code but it does not work like my want. İts printing just this;
`1,1,1,1,1`

```
for($k=0;$k<5;$k++){
    if(in_array($arr1[$k],$tar)){
       echo '1,';
    } else {
       echo '0,';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a variant that is a bit cleaned up:

```
<?php
$arr1 = ['2019-10-3', '2019-10-9', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-21'];
$arr2 = [];
for($i = 1; $i < 31; $i++) { 
    $arr2[] = sprintf("%d-%d-%d", date('Y'), date('m'), $i);
}

$output = [];
for($k = 0; $k < 30; $k++) {
    $output[] = in_array($arr2[$k], $arr1) ? '1' : '0';
}

echo implode(", ", $output);
```

And here a variant that is slightly slower but has a much better readability and robustness:

```
<?php
$arr1 = ['2019-10-3', '2019-10-9', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-21'];
$arr2 = [];
for($i=1;$i<31;$i++) { 
    $arr2[$i] = sprintf("%d-%d-%d", date('Y'), date('m'), $i);
}

$output = [];
foreach($arr2 as $val) {
    $output[] = in_array($val, $arr1) ? '1' : '0';
}

echo implode(", ", $output);
```

The output of both variants obviously is:

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: You can remove the ternary and just int cast the in_array result. `(int)in_array($val, $arr1);`

Comment: @Andreas Absolutely true. However I assume that the `1` and `0` is just for demonstration purpose, I expect the OP to actually use different values. Which is the motivation for the ternary operation. Anyway, thanks ;-)

Comment: please take a look at my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330220/why-cant-i-create-monthly-sales-report-with-chart-js-in-codeigniter  question related to this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
<?php
$arr1=array ('2019-10-3', '2019-10-9', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-21');
for($i=1;$i<31;$i++)
{ 
    $arr2[]=date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-'.$i;
}
for($k=0;$k<30;$k++){
      if(in_array($arr2[$k],$arr1)){
             echo '1,';
          } else {
              echo '0,';
          }
       }
?>

 Output: 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Actually no, the output is not what you claim, it will contain a trailing comma, if you are precise... ;-)

Comment: I know, but to avoid it you can just do it like: $k<29 and then do another separate if

Answer (score 0):

While you create your second array you can just test if it's in array 1.

```
$arr1 = ['2019-10-3', '2019-10-9', '2019-10-10', '2019-10-13', '2019-10-17', '2019-10-21'];


for($i=1;$i<31;$i++){ 
    $date = date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-'.$i;
    echo $date . ": ";
    if(in_array($date, $arr1)){
         echo "1\n";
    }else{
         echo "0\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2019-10-1: 0
2019-10-2: 0
2019-10-3: 1
2019-10-4: 0
2019-10-5: 0
2019-10-6: 0
2019-10-7: 0
2019-10-8: 0
2019-10-9: 1
2019-10-10: 1
2019-10-11: 0
2019-10-12: 0
2019-10-13: 1
2019-10-14: 0
2019-10-15: 0
2019-10-16: 0
2019-10-17: 1
2019-10-18: 0
2019-10-19: 0
2019-10-20: 0
2019-10-21: 1
2019-10-22: 0
2019-10-23: 0
2019-10-24: 0
2019-10-25: 0
2019-10-26: 0
2019-10-27: 0
2019-10-28: 0
2019-10-29: 0
2019-10-30: 0
```