# Why can't I create monthly sales report with Chart.js in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, chart.js

I have a chart which is created with chart.js

I get the totals on a daily basis from the database, and some days there is no earnings like this:

```
id | seller | date             | quantity | price | total

1    3636    2019-10-09 10:00   4           1,2      4,8
2    3045    2019-10-09 15:51   2           0,6      1,2
3    3636    2019-10-06 11:05   8           1,0      8,0
4    3636    2019-10-04 14:03   5           0,9      4,5
5    3636    2019-10-01 14:57   3           0,4      1,2
```

Like you see, there are 2 sales on October 9, 1 sale on October 6, 5 sales on October 4, and 1 sale on October 1.

I create a code for this but it does not work very well:

```
//$kazanc_v is sales dates array which is come from the controller
            for($i=1;$i<31;$i++)
            { 
                $arr2[]=date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-'.$i;
            }
            for($k=0;$k<30;$k++){
                  if(in_array($arr2[$k],$kazanc_v[0])){
                         echo $kazanc_v->sub_total;
                      } else {
                          echo '0,';
                }
             }
```

When I get data into data sets the chart looks like this:

[image]

for can't see img: [wrong chart](https://eksiup.com/p/bq258762xap8)

I cant write '0' in charts data because there is no data in table.
I want to write 0 when there is no sale on dates and chart is should be like this which I want

[image: October sales report]
for can't see img : [[october reports][3](https://eksiup.com/p/w82588177qph)](https://eksiup.com/p/w82588177qph)

How can I create real report?

Comment: There may be a more elegant way, but this has worked for me in the past. First generate an array with keys (and default `0` values) of the dates you want to view. Then you can iterate over that array to populate it with existing data from your DB. That way, all dates have an entry and a value, so outputting it in chart.js becomes trivial.

Comment: ı add  codes which ı get datas from controller to view but it is not write '0' on non sales dates because there is no data

Comment: Can you post the actual JS that's generated (and is creating the chart)? It's _really_ hard to help much further with only images showing that it's not working.

Comment: js file is come from original chart.js website [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js)
ı have no problem about js file. 
my problem is on my code. ı can't write '0' on the dataset of  javascript

  for($i=1;$i<31;$i++)
            { 
                $arr2[]=date('Y').'-'.date('m').'-'.$i;
            }
            for($k=0;$k<30;$k++){
                  if(in_array($arr2[$k],$kazanc_v[0])){
                         echo $kazanc_v->sub_total;
                      } else {
                          echo '0,';
                }
             }

Answer (score 2):

First of all, lets make it clear a bit, i see `$kazanc_v[0]` and `$kazanc_v->sub_total` is this and object or array? What is the output of this variable?

Also working with such output will force you do a mistake. If you want to show total count of sales or sum price per date, you should get data from database as grouped by date.

your query in your model should be something like this;

```
//in your model
$this->db->select("count(quantity) as qty, DATE(order_date) as date") 
         ->from("orders")
         ->where(order_date > "2021-01-01") //beginning of this month
         ->group_by('date')
         ->get()
         ->result_array()
 ;
```

Now, you need to create `x-axis` first. 
In your case total day in a month (we consider as 31 days)

```
//in your controller
$begin = new DateTime( date('Y-m-01') ); //or given date
$end = new DateTime( date('Y-m-t') );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
```

you have an array with dates, now you can create your chart data with y and x axis with data coming from your model.

```
$chartData =[];
$kazanc = $this->some_model->some_method();  

foreach($dateRange as $date){
  $dataKey = array_search($date->format("Y-m-d"), array_column($kazanc, 'date'));
  if ($dataKey !== false) { // if we have the data in given date
      $chartData[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = $kazanc[$dataKey]['qty'];
  }else {
      //if there is no record, create default values
     $chartData[$date->format("Y-m-d")] = 0;
  }
}

//send data to view
$this->load->view('template', ["chartData" => $chartData]);
```

now, you have date (x-axis) and qty (y-axis) for 31 days data in `$chartData` variable.

Finally, we can print our data in view. According to chartjs documentation, something like this.

```
// in your view
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
   labels: <?php echo json_encode(array_keys($chartData)); ?>,
   datasets: [
        {
          label: '# Total Quantity',
          data: <?php echo json_encode(array_values($chartData)); ?>,
          borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]
 },
```

sample working code (php) https://www.tehplayground.com/pmiPYk3yhIpExJqa

jsfiddle for chartjs. https://jsfiddle.net/jwf67voe/